# Autowiring of Spring Data Repo fails with Maven Skinny war option

Tags: spring, maven, spring-data, spring-batch-admin

My question is similar to [this one posted a while ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9394745/autowiring-fails-when-jars-are-loaded-as-per-skinny-war-concept-where-classes-i)
The autowiring of Spring Data Repos fail when the external libraries are in EAR's lib folder.

The wiring works fine when all jars are included in *WEB-INF/lib.* 
I tried setting the *'skinnyWar'* to false but this is duplicating the jars in both EAR and WAR.

The application uses Spring Batch Admin 1.2.2 and Spring Data 1.1 with Spring 3.2.2 based.
**Maven Version** used is **3.3**. The runtime is **Websphere** 7.x

I have another application that works perfectly fine with skinnywar set to true - this uses spring-ws, spring-data 4.0.x version.

The WAR POM

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>batchadmin-web</artifactId>
    <parent>
    <groupId>com.xyz.interfaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>batch-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../batch-parent/pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Batch Admin Interface Web</name>
    <dependencies>
<!-- Application specific jars/modules Not included for brevity-->

    </dependencies>

    <build>
            <finalName>springbatch-admin</finalName>
            <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\classes</outputDirectory>
            <testOutputDirectory>${project.basedir}\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\classes</testOutputDirectory>
            <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.4</version>
                            <configuration>
                                    <archive>
                                             <manifest>
                                                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                                                    <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                                            </manifest>
                                     </archive>
                                       <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/spring-beans*.jar</packagingExcludes>  
                            </configuration>
                    </plugin>
            </plugins>
    </build>
    </project>
```

The EAR POM content:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>batchadmin-ear</artifactId>
    <parent>
    <groupId>com.xyz.interfaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>batch-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../batch-parent/pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <packaging>ear</packaging>
    <name>Batch Admin Interface</name>
    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.xyz.interfaces</groupId>
                    <artifactId>batchadmin-web</artifactId>
                    <type>war</type>
                    <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
            <finalName>SpringBatchEAR</finalName>
            <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.9.1</version>

                            <configuration>
                                    <skinnyWars>true</skinnyWars>
                                    <defaultLibBundleDir>lib/</defaultLibBundleDir>
                                    <modules>
                                            <webModule>
                                                    <groupId>com.xyz.interfaces</groupId>
                                                    <artifactId>batchadmin-web</artifactId>
                                                    <contextRoot>/springbatch-admin</contextRoot>
                                                    <bundleFileName>springbatch-admin.war</bundleFileName>
                                            </webModule>
                                    </modules>

                            </configuration>
                    </plugin>
            </plugins>
    </build>
```

**Update**: Since the EAR has only one Web module, used '*Single class loader for application*' for '**WAR class loader policy**' in the Websphere. This way, I am able to make this work.

I would like to know how to make this work without changing the classloader option as this might not be preferred when multiple web modules are present.

Comment: First which maven version do you use? Which version of maven-ear-plugin, maven-war-plugin are you using and how does your pom look like (war, ear)...

Comment: @khmarbaise, I have updated my question with the details of WAR and EAR POM content.